# OpenSSL EVP_PKEY_verify() returns -1

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I wrote a function that should verify a signature by opening a file and checking the signature against `unsigned char buff[]= "data";`.
This function returns -1, which

> indicates an error other than signature verification failure

as per [evp_pkey_verify](https://linux.die.net/man/3/evp_pkey_verify).

What kind of error is this? Why is there no further documentation there? I find it pretty useless if a function returns values that are not described in the function description.

```
bool verify_sig_of_buff(const string & pub_key_file_path, const unsigned char * buff, size_t buff_len, const string & sig){
    FILE * f = fopen(pub_key_file_path.c_str(), "r");
    EC_KEY *ec_key = PEM_read_EC_PUBKEY(f, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    fclose(f);


    EVP_PKEY * key = EVP_PKEY_new();
    assert(1==EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(key, ec_key));

    EVP_PKEY_CTX * key_ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(key,NULL);

    assert(1==EVP_PKEY_verify_init(key_ctx));
    assert(1==EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md(key_ctx, EVP_sha256()) );
    size_t sig_len=0;

    const int ret=EVP_PKEY_verify(key_ctx, (unsigned char * )&sig[0],sig.size(), buff , buff_len);

    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(key_ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_free(key);

    cout<<ret<<endl;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the OpenSSL error queue? E.g. through ERR_print_errrors_fp() or similar?